# Tomcat PermGen Memory

Tags: tomcat, permgen

Hey I'm on windows and I'm trying to deploy Tomcat but I keep getting a permgen memory exception. I read you can modify `catalina.bat` by adding `JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms128M -Xmx256M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"`, but where the does that go? I replaced all references to `JAVA_OPTS` (which seemed to use a variable `%JAVA_OPTS%`) with the above text, and tomcat didn't even open that little console window when I attempted to deploy it. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

You probably left a syntax error and Tomcat exited early. If you want to see that error, type `catalina run` in the command line and you will see the output.

In any case, the proper/official way to make those changes is to put them in `setenv.bat` (create if does not exist) which will be picked up by `catalina.bat`/`startup.bat`.